# Excel Distinct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I  am trying to return a distinct list with another column as its condition. I tried the unique function and it works but I am not sure how to add another condition. Please see below table and expected output

Raw Data

```
apple | Deejay
banana | Deejay
Mango | Deejay
Apple | Deejay
kiwi | Ann
Apple | Ann
Melon | Deejay
Melon | Deejay
```

output

```
Value "Deejay"
Apple
Banana
Mango
Melon
```

So far this is the formula I'm using

```
=UNIQUE(E4:E11,FALSE,FALSE)
```

it is similar to Count IF but there is no uniqueIF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNIQUE with FILTER & MATCH

[image]

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(E4:E11,ISNUMBER(MATCH(F4:F11,I4,0))))
```

---

Using XMATCH with FILTER

[image]

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(E4:E11,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(F4:F11,I4))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNIQUE` with `FILTER`:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(E4:E11,F4:F11="Deejay"))
```

[image]

Comment: I was going to answer exactly the same. So i had to change lol!